# UICollectionView Magic Selection

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I added collection view and add selection events:

```
private func addFriendCollectionView() {
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    let cellSize = (mainContainerView?.frame.width)! / 4

    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 50, right: 10)

    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellSize, height: cellSize)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 50.00

    let positionRectangle = CGRect(x: 5, y: 230, width: (mainContainerView?.frame.width)!, height: 300)

    friendsCollection = UICollectionView(frame: positionRectangle, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    friendsCollection?.registerClass(FriendCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "friendCell")
    friendsCollection?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    friendsCollection!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    friendsCollection!.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

    friendsCollection?.tag = 1
    friendsCollection?.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    friendsCollection?.dataSource = self
    friendsCollection?.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(friendsCollection!)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if collectionView.tag == 1 {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FriendCollectionViewCell

        selectedFriends[indexPath] = cell.friendName.text

        cell.selectBlackView.hidden = false
        cell.selectedImage.hidden = false



        print("\(selectedFriends.count) - \(indexPath)")

    } else if collectionView.tag == 2 {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DateSelectionCollectionViewCell

        print("\(cell.weekday.text) and \(indexPath)")
    }
}
```

But selection layer add every cell with offset 9. If i am select 1 selected 10, 19, 28... etc but indexPath change correct

Comment: Can you try with `selectedFriends[indexPath.row]` Can you also show the `collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)`

Comment: All problem in            ``` let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FriendCollectionViewCell
            cell.selectBlackView.hidden = true
            cell.selectedImage.hidden = true ```